# Use NEST > 1.9.1 with ElasticSearch 1.7?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST 1.9.1 with ElasticSearch 1.7.

This version of NEST doesn't have index type for nested nor does it have retry for updates.

I'm not sure yet what version of NEST those things are added in, but I am wondering if it's fine to use a higher version of NEST with version 1.7 of ElasticSearch.
Basically is NEST backwards compatible with version 1.9.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  NEST 1.x should be compatible with any ES 1.x.

When you move to ES 2.x you should also upgrade to NEST 2.x

When you move to ES 5.x you should also upgrade to NEST 5.x

Comment: Just to clarify, I can use NEST 2.x with ES 1.x but I should try to upgrade ES to 2.x when I can. Correct?

Comment: Correct.  ES 5.x is actually the latest stable release.

Comment: Not _quite_ correct; NEST 2.x should only be used with Elasticsearch 2.x. If you're still on Elasticsearch 1.x, use the latest NEST 1.x version: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#compatibility-matrix There are breaking changes in Elasticsearch that are reflected in changes to NEST; whilst it may work for the most part, there are known places where it will not